# Is it worth fighting for wages owed if your client was the public state?

Tags: salary, legal, government, argentina

I know it varies greatly depending on the culture of the country, but we may be able to establish an average. I was hired to program for the police. This body depends directly on the provincial government, (Argentina is divided into 24 states, called provinces). I started working in October 2015, and they only started paying me since March 2016. As of today, I was paid for 2015, but I am owed all the amount worked in January and February 2016.

Today a WhatsApp group was set up with all the people in the same condition as me, with the aim of paying us. They are supposed to want to pay us, but using the value that was paid in 2016. From 2016 to 2021, due to the horrible inflation, my salary was **TRIPLED**. So receiving two salaries in 2016 is much less than what I earn now in a month.

In summary ... I wanted to ask about similar experiences, to ask if in these conditions looking for a lawyer is useful, or if my enemy is too powerful not to be a lost fight beforehand ... Or if the lawyer's expenses will be higher than the profit. Or even if I can report some type of abuse or moral damages received by this situation.

It should be noted that there are approximately 50 people in the same situation as I, but since they continue to work for the state (I was the only one who resigned), they do not want to risk losing their job by reporting.

Comment: Why are you only looking at legal action 5 years later?

Comment: @Kilisi Because if I did, I would lose my job. Or I was vulnerable to some kind of indirect punishment, like being transferred to another city of the province without my consent (it's something that is done a lot ... they use it as revenge). But I quit in February and started working for a company in March.

Comment: Only a lawyer is going to help you here.

Comment: It's not really helpful to you, but in most western countries the government can certainly be sued. It's possible that the Law SE may be able to give you their opinion if this is a flat out waste of time, but if there is a lot of money on the table, it may be worthwhile speaking to a lawyer. (As DJClayworth has said).

Comment: @Gregory Currie Agree. That is also what the question points to, if in addition to demanding the salaries paid with today's values, if they give me another compensation for damages, and if so, how much money are we talking about. It is a variable to consider if reacting like this with my client is profitable, or not, for me.

Comment: @TomuRain The likely-hood of anyone on Workplace SE being able to give you an indication on how compensation for damages is going to be incredibly low. It will depend on a range of factors that only a lawyer can work through.

Comment: Also, you say you seem to be contradicting yourself. If they were your client, then you didn't receive wages. Wages are only for employees. This distinction is very important. Usually, your rights differ based on whether you were an employee or a contractor. In any case, if this happened to many of you, and assuming you were all employees, maybe you could pool your money and hire a lawyer for an initial consultation.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at a government trying to stay out of default. Hyperinflation is exactly why they're delaying you. As a member of a family under the exact same situation in Venezuela, here's my (personal) advice  backed by experience:

The government of Argentina, like that of Venezuela, is using hyperinflation to offset unpayable debts to other countries. They are not going to help you here unless you have some type of leverage. They have creditors with a lot more leverage on them, and to whom they owe money, for whom delaying payment until after the money is devalued is much more profitable. In general this is the case in countries with debt problems. If waiting a year means you have to pay 1/3 of the value, why wouldn't you? Even a lawyer is not going to get you over the amount owed you plus interest at some bank standard rate, which is likely set by your government at far below the inflation rate.

Instead of focusing on getting the now devalued money (or at any rate a larger amount than they originally promised) I would negotiate or work on a freelance basis under the stipulation that: You own all software and employ solutions to disable or rescind access until the money is paid, or; negotiate your salary in a currency of your choice. In Venezuela, due to the hyperinflation there, it is not unheard of to work for an amount of Bolivars equal to that day's exchange rate to USD.

Comment: Doesn't your solution become a "Chicken and Egg" problem?  "We won't pay you until you do the work", "Well I'm not giving you the work until you pay me!".

Comment: @PeterM Unfortunately you're right, that's why the second solution is also proposed. In any case, what value is a job that doesn't pay you for years until the money is worthless? It's much better to quit and look for a job in the private sector.